# Facebook & Twitter share buttons in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, twitter, share

My asp.net web page shows a list of Youtube videos. I want to show "Share on Facebook" and "Share on Twitter" links with each video icon.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [Add This](http://www.addthis.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Document provides links](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) for Facebook Social Plugins such as (Like Button,Send button,Comments,Like Box.etc.) and how to integrate into your site with just line of HTML code.

[Document](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites) for the Tweet button, Follow button and how can you embed them on your website with just one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this one for facebook share button, twitter share button, linkedin share button with callback function just pass your link and share:

[Social share buttons facebook,twitter,linkedin in asp.net](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2012/06/social-share-buttons-in-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add This is good option otherwise if you wants to add just Twitter only then below code will help you out.

[Add Tweet To Asp.NET Website](http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-add-tweet-this-button-to-aspnet.html)